# How use [optionalTrackingData] with viber-bot

Tags: node.js, viber, viber-bot

I want to get some extra data from the user in my viber bot. This can be done via [optionalTrackingData]. But no matter how hard I try to send a message with [optionalTrackingData], the message from the user is always empty. Maybe there are some additional settings? I write on Node.js

this what I tried:
bot.sendMessage(response.userProfile, [
new TextMessage("please select your email:"),
keyboardMessage
], {'trackingData':'trackingData'});

please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok, I just reload mode.js and it start working